# Is Sharepoint List item update using REST API return updated data

Tags: sharepoint-online, updatelistitems, sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to update custom list item using **REST API**.

I  was successfully updated item but in response of request i am not getting updated record.

I want to store updated `etag` but  I am getting `204` response code and no content message.

How can I get updated Record in response.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SharePoint REST API does not return the updated item/object after updating it. You are right! It only returns status code `204` if the update request is successful.

So to get updated item/object, you have to make another **GET** request.

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('list name')/items(item id)
```